# Pausing and resuming swing Timer

Tags: java, swing

I want to pause and resume my snake game when I hit space button.

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE) {
    timer.stop();
}

if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER ) {
    timer.start();
}
```

I've done this but to resume the game I need to hit "Enter" any idea?

Comment: `timer.stopIfStartedOrStartIfStopped()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I've done this but to resume the game I need to hit "Enter" any idea?

You can use the same KeyStroke to stop/start the Timer. Just check the status of the Timer:

```
if (timer.isRunning())
    timer.stop();
else
    timer.start();
```

Also, don't use a KeyListner for this. You should be using [Key Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) to map a `KeyStroke` to an `Action`.

Answer (score 0):

@retatu thanks for the idea i found the solution i just needed to initialize the locker in the constructor like that

```
public Controller(Snake snake,View view) {
    this.snake = snake;
    this.view = view;
    locker = false;
}
```

and then use it in the code

```
if (keyCode == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE ){
        if(!locker){
            view.timer.stop();
            locker=true;
        }else{
            locker = false;
            view.timer.start();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Good job bro =)

Comment: There is no need for a "locker" variable, just use the methods of the Timer.